# Firebug can't set local storage

Tags: firefox, firebug, local-storage

Why does Firebug always report the window.localStorage object as empty?  If I open the console and type,

```
>>> window.localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar')
undefined

>>> window.localStorage
0 items in Storage
```

Is there some security setting that is preventing me from using localStorage?

Answer (score 1):

Your page is presumably https, which causes Firebug [not to be able to read localStorage](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5040).